# Event email receipt doesn't have Total amount data

Tags: civievent, email, paypal

The email receipt which is sent after registering for an event is not having the "Total Amount" data and it is showing blank in the row. This is happening with "PayPal - Website Payments Standard" payment processor. It is working correctly for Pay Later method.

If the email receipt is sent from the list of contributions through admin interface then it is showing correctly, I tried by changing the tokens in the message template for "Event registration (online)" but it is not working. Please help me to fix this issue.

Thank you

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you on? I have seen that it was recently fixed. But I cannot remember where.

Comment: @JaapJansma-CiviCooP The CiviCRM version is 5.14.1

Comment: Can you check whether this is still a problem in the latest version? You can check the latest version on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org